# WebSphere Process Server sends empty body

Tags: websphere-7, wid, websphere-process-server

We have a problem that happens sometimes without any pattern we are able to see.

We log a request just before a callout, it looks fine, with data in the body. When the request arrives at the service we are calling the body is empty.

We restarted the development machine, did not help.

We then add a tunnel to see what is being sent out it starts working. Take the tunnel away and it still works.

Next day it stops working again, we put the tunnel back and it still does not work.

Anyone any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been a dependency that we had included, but did not use. When we removed the dependency and republished it started working again.

We think that the contents in this dependency generated a namespace conflict, but this only shows up when some other part of the system has loaded these files.